# Multiple installs of Python on MacOSX for Eclipse

Tags: python, macos, pydev, virtualenv, python-2.x

I want to have multiple installs of Python: 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, 3.x
My IDE is Eclipse (Helios)/Pydev on MacOSX, which works great. I have a couple of Python codebases that are/will be running on different versions of Python. Also, I like Eclipse PyDev's crosslinking from source-code to documentation.

The standard recommendation seems to be: use virtualenv, and keep the installs totally separate from the builtin MacPython (2.6.1). Eclipse should never be pointing to the MacPython install. (Should PYTHONPATH even be set in such an environment?)

Before I get on with virtualenv, is there anything else I should know about this?
virtualenv doesn't impose any overhead, and I shouldn't be worried with occasional comments about breakage to nose, coverage etc?

I'm interested in hearing from Eclipse or Pydev users on MacOS.
Also if anyone has other tips on migrating a Python codebase from 2.1 -> 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to  use [macport](http://www.macports.org/) to install the different version of pythons. It will have different versions of all packages for all versions of pythons that you want. They will be installed in */opt/local/*. 
So in Eclipse with PyDev for a particular project you can right click into the name of the project -> properties: There, in the left you choose *PyDev - Interpreter/Grammar*. And you click the link *Click here to configure an interpreter not lister*. You click on *new* on the top right of the new window. You give the name of the version of python you want to create the interpreter for, if you have already installed it with all required package through *macport*. And in the field *Intepreter Executable* you give the path: **/opt/local/bin/pythonX.X** . 
After, in the previous option window: *PyDev - Intepreter/Grammar*, you can choose in the *Interpreter* menu the python version that you just installed.

For the shell, and the default path pointing to **/usr/bin/python** you **must** use: **python_select** (installed through macport) instead of playing with the *env* variables. Afterward you can use *macport* to update/install new packages, make sure everything is alway clean.

Comment: Forgot about macports completely, been some while since I used OS X now. This is much better than what I suggested :)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly right. You didn't explicitly say why but [PyDev - Interpreter scanning does not seem to automatically find a Macport install of python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610272/pydev-doesnt-find-python-library-after-installation/6144832#6144832).

Answer (score 1):

Having [Home Brew](https://brew.sh/) already installed in your system, I recommend you [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Most of the following information comes from [this quick installation/use guide](http://%20%20[3]:%20https://www.developerfiles.com/installing-multiple-python-versions-in-mac-os-x/):

**Installing pyenv + pyenv-virtualenv**

1. Go to your terminal and install pyenv and the external libraries needed by Python:

   ```
   brew update
   brew install pyenv openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
   ```
2. Add `pyenv init` to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion running the following command:

   ```
   echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
3. Install the **pyenv-virtualenv** plugin so you can create virtual environments for each version of Python:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv.git $(pyenv root)/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv
   echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
   ```
4. Reset your terminal to apply the changes `exec "$SHELL"` or just close your terminal and open a new one.

**Gettings different Python versions**

We can list all available versions with `pyenv install --list`:

```
pyenv install --list
Available versions:
  2.7.15
  3.0.1
  ..
  3.7.2
```

For installing the Python version 3.7.2:

```
pyenv install 3.7.2
```

With pyenv versions you can see all the Python versions installed in your computer:

```
root@Host ~$ pyenv versions
* 3.7.2
```

**Creating a virtual environment**

In the previous step we have downloaded the Python 3.7.2 interpreter, we can now use it to create an isolated virtual environment. This is very useful for software development, keeping each project completely isolated from the others:

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.7.2 MY_VIRTUALENV_NAME
```

To list all your virtual environments:

```
pyenv virtualenvs
```

To activate a virtual environment:

```
pyenv activate MY_VIRTUALENV_NAME
```

To deactivate the currently active virtual environment:

```
pyenv deactivate
```

Comment: How do you configure Eclipse to use this virtualenv?

Comment: I think it was within `Eclipse Settings -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python interpreter`. Then add the path of the corresponding python binary env, in mi example it would be `~/.pyenv/versions/MY_VIRTUALENV_NAME/bin/python`. But it depends where you have installed .pyenv.

Comment: Ah, PyDev. Unfortunately in my situation I'm not using PyDev, just need Eclipse to find pyenv (or at least the right Python version within pyenv). In my case I ended up prepending to `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

From the README text file of python

> ### Installing multiple versions
>
> On Unix and Mac systems if you intend
>   to install multiple versions of Python
>   using the same installation prefix
>   (--prefix argument to the configure
>   script) you must take care that your
>   primary python executable is not
>   overwritten by the installation of a
>   different version.  All files and
>   directories installed using "make
>   altinstall" contain the major and
>   minor version and can thus live
>   side-by-side.  "make install" also
>   creates ${prefix}/bin/python which
>   refers to ${prefix}/bin/pythonX.Y.  If
>   you intend to install multiple
>   versions using the same prefix you
>   must decide which version (if any) is
>   your "primary" version.  Install that
>   version using "make install".  Install
>   all other versions using "make
>   altinstall".
>
> For example, if you want to install
>   Python 2.5, 2.6 and 3.0 with 2.6 being
>   the primary version, you would execute
>   "make install" in your 2.6 build
>   directory and "make altinstall" in the
>   others.

Virtualenv is an option but you could use the above mentioned option instead of venv which seems much simpler.

Comment: Thanks. There's more to it than clobbering an existing install - MacOS is supposed to have dependencies on the version and libraries with MacPython (2.6.1). I may not strictly need venv but I want the peace of mind that a package will never get installed in the wrong place - opinions?

Comment: I think you should try what @Zenon suggests and try macports if you have not already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `conda` to create multiple environments (mostly, you create a new env, activate it and install the packages you want there -- using `conda` itself if possible or `pip` if it's not available in `conda`). See: https://conda.io/docs/installation.html.

After you have an environment created, you just need to add a new interpreter inside PyDev which points to the interpreter in the created environment. Ssee: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html.