# pydev eclipse unresolved import within package

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have a basic project hierarchy that goes project->src->package->module.  When I try to import a module to another module within the same package, I get an unresolved import error.
I made sure the interpreters system PYTHONPATH includes the /site-packages folder.
I tried rescanning the folder as seen here: [pydev doesn't find python library after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610272/pydev-doesnt-find-python-library-after-installation), and also tried removing and adding the interpreter again to force it to rescan.

Importing works properly in terminal, just not in eclipse, but sys.path is the same in eclipse and in terminal, except when I view sys.path through eclipse it includes Users/user/Documents/workspace/project/src.

How do I get eclipse to easily import modules within the same package?

Comment: The problem is most likely that the current PYTHONPATH is your source folder rather than the package. Therefore, you can either move the modules up a level to be within the source folder or add the path to the package as an external library.